# Are Thalia and Batman hats mutally exclusives?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2015

I got Batman for [editing a question that was reopened](//askubuntu.com/posts/337212/revisions). Cool. But I also participated in the process, so I should also get Thalia hat, no? Can I get another hat in the process of being awarded one?

Comment: You obviously can't be Batman and Talia at the same time, duh!

Comment: He can become Damian Wayne then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, they're not mutually exclusive, and you would have received the Thalia had you cast your reopen vote twelve seconds later :)

But you voted to reopen at 23:59:48, and thus not during Winter Bash.

Comment: DAMN!!!!!!!!!!!!! :/